# How to use ngrx in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, ngrx

Can i use ngrx for angularjs application?

Any reference or sample project?

Inspired by downgrading option in the ngrx official site [Downgrading for angularjs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/recipes/downgrade)

Comment: looks like you need to bootstrap your angularjs application with angular to get the module to work correctly.  see the discussion in the answer below, particularly the last few posts

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is already working somehow...  https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/98